# startActivityForResult() not working for external Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This is not a duplicate question. I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919259/how-to-get-startactivityforresult-on-external-activity-to-work) question relevant but it doesn't have any working solution.

**What I Have**

I have two apps both created by me, App A and App B. My requirement is to open App B from App A on click of a button. Now, App B will do some processing and return a small status to App A. This should be possible isn't it?

**What I Have Done**

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(Config._PACKAGE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 6699);
```

This opens the App B perfectly. Now in App B,

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("STATUS", statusCode);
 setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
 finish();
```

And this is my `onActivityResult()` method on the Activity. I am starting the Activity from a Fragment though.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.d(TAG, "ON ACTIVITY RESULT");

        if (requestCode == 6699) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Log.d(TAG, "RESULT OK");

            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                Log.d(TAG, "RESULT NOT OK");

            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

The `onActivityResult()` gets called just when I start the activity of App B with `RESULT_CANCELLED.` How is this possible? Is it because its a new task?

But when I call `finish()` on App B and it closes and takes me back to App A, but the `onActivityResult()` is not called this time? How can I solve this?

**This is a very basic requirement and should have a solution.**

Comment: From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29): "if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result"

Comment: There is no launchMode mentioned for the Activity in App B in its manifest. What is wrong then?

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved this problem.

> if the activity you are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it
>   will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a
>   cancel result

This is what the docs says. Now the idea is that if the called activity is started on a new task, the result will be cancelled immediately. In my case, I am starting an activity from a different app altogether, which is always started in a new task, regardless of any `launchMode` or `taskAffinity` or flag.

Whenever I do something like this,

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(Config._PACKAGE);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 6699);
```

this flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is automatically added by default. So, we need to clear all flags before starting the activity using,

```
intent.setFlags(0);
```

Use it before calling `startActivity()`. The solution was simple and tricky at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You really should add in a custom Intent Filter to make this happen. This will allow you to direct the flow for your task that you want Application B to do, separate from how you might use Application B. See [Android docs Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) for how to do this. Basically, you add a blurb into the manifest for Application B, something like this:

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Application A will use something like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textMessage);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

// Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

These of course will need to be customized for your application.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide an example on how it should be done? I have posted all I have done in my question.

Comment: Should I use startActivity() and not startActivityForResult()?

Comment: Yes, startActivityForResults is the correct way to get the information.

Comment: How does this solve the problem where onActivityResult() is not getting called?

Comment: AFAICT, it does not. @PearsonArtPhoto, would you like to explain how this answers the question?

Comment: You are basically starting the activity from scratch, as I understand, which Android might assume has no results. It might only work if you aren't using the launcher intent. I'm not 100% sure, but it seems the most logical solution to your problem.